# Changing color scheme of console output in mRemoteNG

Tags: console, color-scheme, mremoteng

I use mRemoteNG to handle all my remote connections to servers. The only negative point I have run into is that the colorscheme of console output is not good. Directories are listed in dark blue and on a black background this is barely readable.

How can I change the colorscheme to something else?

Comment: It's actually very annoying, thanks for asking :) The answer is a sum of eztechman + user3143184

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**For a specific session:**

Right click on the console, this should display the putty settings, you will be able to change color scheme in Windows --> Colours

**To change default:**

- In mRemoteNG Tools --> Advanced --> Launch Putty
- Change color settings as described above
- Click Session
- Select "Default Settings"
- Click Save
- Click Close

Comment: This does not work when I close and reopen the session. So the settings are transient. Did you figure out a way in which you can persist the colors so that it is applied in the next session as well?

Comment: If you want to make your settings persistent, before to push the Apply button in the putty settings menu, you have to:
1) go to the "Session" tab
2) select the "Default Settings"
3) click Save

Answer (score 10):

The colours you need to change in the putting settings after using the Ctrl+right-click and selecting "settings" are the following:

1. ANSI Blue
2. ANSI Blue Bold

Answer (score 2):

To change the Font size in mRemoteNG:
Open mRemoteNG normally

```
go to Tools

go to options

go to advanced
```

in the open dialog box to the right you will see an option **Launch PuTTY**, click on it,
The PuTTY window opens up,

```
Go to appearance/Font Settings,

Click on 'Change',

Select Font/Font style/size,

Click OK at the bottom.
```

And you are good to go.
this worked on my notebook Windows 7.
if you need any help on this topic, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share my solution using Kitty (should work also for Putty after modifying registry key)

Kitty uses a sessions folder to store its settings, so no registry key changes need to be performed to get this working.

Steps for Kitty

1. Install MRemoteNG
2. Go to install directory (default C:\Program Files (x86)\mRemoteNG )
3. Rename PuTTYNG.exe to PuTTYNG.exe.bak
4. Copy the Kitty portable executable and sessions folder to the installation location of MRemoteNG
5. Rename Kitty.exe with PuTTYNG.exe
6. Open MRemoteNG session and enjoy a solarized terminal!

[MremoteNG Solarized terminal using Kitty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmqGC.png)

Source

Kitty solarized themes: https://github.com/yograf/kitty-solarized

Putty themes: https://github.com/AlexAkulov/putty-color-themes

Note: Putty requires registry key modification to replace the color scheme.

Answer (score 0):

I could not save the settings. The decision that others suggested did not help.
How I solved the problem:

1. Uploaded the color scheme. I saved it through the registry.
2. Opened PuttyNG settings
3. Selected a saved session (optional, you can make changes to the settings)
4. Entered the line "Default Settings" and save.

In this way, I managed to change the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and safest way to do it, works on your office laptop too since registry modification is prohibited there.

1. putty > window > appearance > adjust font size and type > click ok
2. putty > window > colours > choose foreground/background etc., > modify > choose color> click ok
3. click session > default settings > save.
   Now try opening an ssh from this putty session and verify that the default settings are applied and all sessions are looking the way you wanted.
4. mremoteng > tools > options > advanced > use custom putty path > select your putty.exe > click ok
   Enjoy your custom settings, colors and fonts.

Answer (score 0):

The change from mremoteng didn't work. Had to go to the putty app and make the change advised above, and rebooted the mremoteng seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is:

- Modify in regular Putty your custom settings.
- Then in every mRemoteNG connection, choose the Putty Session you want.
  And that's it

Next time you open your mremoteng session, it'll with the new color settings.

In regular Putty modify one session with your custom settings.
In mremoteng, on every connection you want to change, under ***Config panel*** > ***Protocol section***, change the ***PuTTY Session*** parameter from *Default Settings* to the session you modified in the previous step.